# How to kill a thread in android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I've got a background thread running in my application and I need to kill it safely. How can I kill a thread in java other than using a boolean flag? I have read that i cannot use thread.stop() anymore as it is not safe. but is there a proper way of doing this? can someone give me a code snippet for it please?

Thanks

Comment: Why doesn't a flag work? Does the thread wait for something to happen?

Comment: why don't you like boolean flag solution?

Comment: I could use a boolean flag to work. But I'm trying to find out if there is another way of doing it? as an example in C# I think You can abort a thread.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its never safe in any language to kill a thread- you don't know what that thread may be doing and what state it may leave behind.  Using the cancel method with the thread occassionally checking isCanceled allows the thread to manage its own safety-  it can choose to do this only when it would be safe to kill itself or to do the needed cleanup.

If you don't actually need to kill a thread but just want to wait until its over, use join.

If you absolutely need to kill a thread, go ahead and use stop.  Just don't expect your state to be safe or consistent afterwards-  this should really only be done when terminating the application/activity.

Comment: Yes you are right stop() is deprecated and It is not safe to use. I have used a Boolean to stop any threads that I have been using in my code.

Answer (score 5):

Try using something like

```
service.getThread().interrupt();
service.setThread(null);
```

Or

```
thread.interrupt();
thread = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need using flag. For ex:

```
private boolean isThOn; //flag isThOn
long delaytime;
int times;
...
new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            int i=0;
            isThOn = true;
            while (isThOn && i<times) {
                try {
                    i++;
                    //{...}
                    if (i == times) isThOn = false;
                    sleep(delaytime);
                } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            }
        }
}.start();
public void cancelthd() {
    isThOn = false; //whileloop will stop if isThOn = false -> Thread will Terminated befor i = times.
}
```